# How do I translate this SQL query to Typeorm

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I have this query that I tested in the query tool, and I now wish to apply this into Typeorm syntax

```
SELECT menu_entry.*, "user_menu".is_bookmark FROM menu_entry
LEFT JOIN "user_menu"  ON user_menu.menu_id = menu_entry.id
LEFT JOIN "user"  ON "user".id = user_menu.user_id
WHERE "user".id = 1
```

I have tried this approach but it's not 100% correct:

```
async findUserBookmarks(request): Promise<any>{
    const user: any = await createQueryBuilder(User, 'user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('menu_id', 'menu_entry')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.id', 'roles')
    .where('user.id = :id', {id:1 })
    .getMany()

    return console.log('user: ', user);
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using left joins?  The original query is using inner joins.

Comment: What are the entities you have? Can you provide them as well?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan User entity, MenuEntry entity which is a N:N between user and menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class defined for the entity `menu_entry` is `MenuEntry`, typeorm query statement would be as follows-

```
async findUserBookmarks(request): Promise<any>{
    return await getRepository(MenuEntry).
    .createQueryBuilder("menuEntry")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user_menu","userMenu","userMenu.menu_id = menuEntry.id")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user","user","user.id = userMenu.user_id")
    .where("user.id = 1" )
    .getMany()
}
```